# get Element from jquery object

Tags: jquery, html

i have this html element:

```
    <tr style="cursor: pointer" onclick="doWithThisElement(this)">
     <td scope="row">position</td>
     <td>Machine 345</td>
     <td>30</td>
    </tr>
```

the onclick function passes me a jquery object. I would like to get the 'Machine 345' as a string.

what i tried so far is:

```
function doWithThisElement(elem) {
    var test = $(elem).children()[1].get(0);
}
```

when I log it, it gives me:

Machine 345

but as a Object.

Comment: Have you tried .text() on the jquery object?

Comment: `$(elem).children()[1].get(0)` doesn't make a whole lot of sense. a dom node shouldn't have a get method?

Comment: i tried text(), and yes get(0) does not make sense :), i was desperately trying everything what came in my mind and forgot to delete it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function doWithThisElement(elem) {
    var td = $(elem).children('td')[1];
    var test = $(td).text();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla js solution...

```
function doWithThisElement(elem) {
    var test = elem.children[1].innerText;
    console.log(test);
}
```

Jquery solution...

```
function doWithThisElement(elem) {
    var test = $(elem).children().get(1).textContent 
    console.log( test );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you want to get a specific column or if you want to catch any data if you click in a specific row. Otherwise, I can propose you this solution :
https://jsfiddle.net/ckr41w86/

JS

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("#your-id").on('click', function(){
    console.log( $( this ).children().get(1).textContent );
   });
});
```

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr style="cursor: pointer" id="your-id">
    <td scope="row">position</td>
    <td>Machine 345</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```